# How to find that the power Bi embedded apptoken has expired?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We provide the time validity to apptoken in "exp" claim.
Now once the token gets expired the Iframe shows message "Content is not avaible".
My question is how to programmatically detect if the token has expired?, so that i can generate a new apptoken.

Comment: How your code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

When listening to errors, as in: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events#full-list-of-events-and-their-response-values
you can subscribe to report.on('error', ...) and access the message propery in the error object to detect token expiration.

Once detected, you can use the JS SDK to apply a new token without having to reload the embedded report
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Update-Embed-Token

of course, by using 'exp' in your JWT token, you can always set a timer to refresh the token